# Blank line not being stored as null, while loop wont terminate

Tags: java

In my program I'm reading from a .dat file that I put below, I want the while loop to stop when it get to the line of empty space. in my code I have it set up to when words[0] is equal to null it will stop. but this doesn't happen and I end up getting an error. when i change it to words[0] != null or != " " neither seem to work.

DAT

```
1 2
1 3
2 2
2 3
2 6
3 4
3 5
4 1
4 4
4 5
5 5
5 6
5 7
5 9
6 1
6 8
7 7
7 8    
7 9
8 8
8 10
9 8
9 10
10 10
10 4

1 10 10
1 5 2
2 4 7
3 9 4
3 10 1
3 4 3
5 8 2
9 10 1
7 10 4
6 9 3
2 9 5
4 8 2
```

PROGRAM

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class matrix{

public static void main(String[] args){
int[][] arrayNums = new int[9][9];
String[] words = new String[10];

// Location of file to read
    File file = new File("p8.dat");

 try {           
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("p8.dat")));

     words[0]="-1";//TO initiate while loop    
     while(words[0] != null){   
    words=br.readLine().split(" ");

        if(words[0]!= null){


            int num=Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
            int numTwo=Integer.parseInt(words[1]);

            System.out.println(num+" "+numTwo);
}//END IF



}//END WHILE


    }//END TRY---------------------------------------------------------

catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println("Error: Target File Cannot Be Read");
}

}//end main-----------------------------------------------------------
}//end class
```

OUTPUT

```
1 2
1 3
2 2
2 3
2 6
3 4
3 5
4 1
4 4
4 5
5 5
5 6
5 7
5 9
6 1
6 8
7 7
7 8
7 9
8 8
8 10
9 8
9 10
10 10
10 4
Error: Target File Cannot Be Read
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to stop when it get to the line of empty space. in my code I have it set up to when words[0] is equal to null it will stop

A [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) will only return `null` if the end of stream is reached. To check for empty lines, check the length of the returned String - if the length is 0 then you've reached the empty line ( you may also choose to trim the line to ensure leading and trailing whitespace is omitted when calculating the length)

```
String line = br.readLine();

if(line.trim().length() != 0){
    //line is not empty
}
```

Comment: Ok and could explain what you meant by end of stream for future reference please.

Comment: _In the context of reading a File_, `end of stream` means the end of the File.

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
{           
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("p8.dat")));

     while (true)
     {   
         String line = br.readLine();

         if (line == null)
         {
              // end of file! then exit the loop
              break;
         }
         if (line.trim().length() == 0) 
         {
             // the line is empty! then goto next line
             continue;
         }   

         String[] words = line.split(" ");

         int num=Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
         int numTwo=Integer.parseInt(words[1]);

         System.out.println(num+" "+numTwo);
     }
}
```